# Collect inputs from a print line

Tags: c++

I was wondering if it was possible to collect inputs from a print line using `cout`.

Instead of just leaving this as an open-ended question I have attempted to do it myself but when it is running no text appears but an input is still taken from the console if that makes any sense...

```cpp
if (username == "store1") {
    cout << "           Password: " << (cin >> password, password) << endl;
    if (password != "password") {
        cout << "Invalid Password. Try again \n";
        cin.ignore();
        system("pause");
        system("CLS");
    }
}
```

To give some background: I am making a login system for an application I am working on within the console. I am taking in two inputs `username` and `password` in the example I am only showing a part of the password verification.

My assumption was that for the command line `cout << "          Password: " << (cin >> password, password) << endl;` A print line would display saying `Password:` and then the user would be able to type directly next to that and the code collect the input eg `Password: Admin`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect, but if `username == "store1"` and I enter a password, it will echo that password back to me. If I enter any password but `password` it'll say "`Invalid Password. Try again`".

Comment: The code works they isnt an issue with its functionality as a full code base. The only thing I need assistance with is whats addressed in the question :)

Comment: You mean "I was wondering if it was possible to collect inputs from a print line using `cout`"?

Comment: Yes the long term reason for this is because I want to add a border around the login system on the console so I need something that is within one print statement as just having `cin << password;` under it will cause the border to break in that spot.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand enough about this problem to even ask questions. You won't break anything just because you split it up in multiple statements. Make a [mre] and show what it looks like and how you would like it to look.

Comment: Collecting the output to `cout` can be done though. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/KPra5z3b6)

Comment: Would you like trying to clarify the question? What's the purpose of your unusual input-line? How is it different from doing [this](https://godbolt.org/z/MbfT1P4ee)?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using **getline()** function:

```cpp
  std::string password;
  std::cout << "Password: ";
  getline (std::cin, password);
  
  if(password != "password")
  {
      std::cout << "Invalid Password. Try again \n";
  }
```

Comment: Even tho the question asked is not clear, I'm not sure this is what he asking for.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to remove the cin and endl from the cout line and use the commented cin